# How to retrieve running instances of an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm implementing a DownloadManager-like feature in an application I'm developing. I use AsyncTask to push the download to the background.
This AsyncTask is inside a service named for example `DownloadService` which is instantiated on one of my activities. So this means multiple downloads could be started from different instances of an activity.
What I want to do is to have a particular activity in which I can have all the currently running downloads show their progress and have button to pause or resume the download.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want such thing, you can store in an Array all Async Tasks that get started in the service, and then check their status with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, say I created this array you said. How can I access it in a different activity than the one it was created in? And also how can I add to it across different activities?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of housing `DownloadService` inside an Activity, house it inside you app's `Application` class as a class member instead, as there will exist only one instance of this class per application. You can then retrieve it in you activity by calling `((YourApplication)getApplication()).getDownloadService()`. You will have to:

1. Create a class that extends Application, say YourApplication
2. Declare it in the manifest file's `<application>` tag as `android:name="YourApplication"`
3. Use it in your activity by invoking `((YourApplication)getApplication()).someMethodToGetDownloadService()`

Comment: As I said the `DownloadService` is a separate class (I didn't house it inside my activity, I just instantiate it there).

Comment: Great then instantiate it inside your Application class. Retrieve it in an activity and submit tasks to it. Then you should be able to have a progress activity where you could retrieve all running tasks and allow operations on them.